# MassTransit with TimerTrigger in Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, masstransit, timer-trigger

I want to use MassTransit in an Azure Function triggered by a TimerTrigger. I've tried using the ServiceBusTrigger as the docs suggest http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/azure-functions.html but my downstream services need to be shielded from bursts in the queue.

With MassTransit, is there a way to tell it to Stop the Bus when the queue is empty? At the moment my Function continues to run until the next timer is triggered because the Bus keeps it alive, whereas what I want to do is for the Function to consume any messages in the queue with rate limiting until either the queue is empty or its consumed some number of messages.

Is this possible with MassTransit? Or is this the wrong tool?

Comment: doesn't that sample trigger per message on the bus? (it takes the message as an argument to the function).